# Mysql query fails sometimes not always

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple mysql query in a PHP page. The query is somehow like this-

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_tables");  
echo mysql_num_rows($q);
```

The number of rows in `ip_tables` is simply `5-10`.  The problem is this simple query fails sometimes without any reason. For example, sometimes I load the page and find the error message `Warning: invalid argument supplied to mysql_num_rows. resource required, boolean given in ...`.

But at that moment if I refresh the page, the error does not occur and it shows the correct row number. This problem occurs sometimes not always.
Anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: 1064 is a syntax error. There's no syntax error here - I suspect this is mis-tagged.

Comment: Always check for errors `if (!$q) {echo mysql_error();}`

Comment: It seems that you have a problem with your DB connection or MySQL or you don't have the good right, see that: mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query. (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). It's not a solution, just an observation ! In your case, a boolean is given, which can only be false...

Comment: Is the table engine MyISAM or InnoDB? Do you perhaps do the `"drop table ip_tables"` at some point then recreate it?

Answer (score -1):

Tthis will log mysql error in Your error log file:
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_tables") or error_log(mysql_error());